# Typescript function overloading with object

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts an object as the only parameter. For example:

```
interface MyMap<T> {
  [id: string]: T;
}

type Options = {
  asObject: boolean,
  other?: Function
};

  function get(options: Options): any[];
  function get(options: Options): MyMap<any>;
  function get(options: Options): any[] | MyMap<any>;
  function get(options: Options = {asObject: false, other: () => {}}): any[] | MyMap<any> {
    if (options.asObject) return {} as MyMap<any>;

    return [];
}


const result = get({asObject: true});
```

When the asObject value is true, I want to infer the type to MyMap. I know how to do it with simple boolean value, but how can I accomplish this with an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get(options: {asObject: true}): MyMap<any>;
function get(options: {asObjectb false}): any[];
function get(): any[];
function get(options: Options = {asObject: false, other: () => {}}): any[] | MyMap<any> {
   //  ... 
}
```

Should be all that you need. This will overload the function for the literal types `true` and `false` of the property `asObject`.

Note that when overloads are declared, the implementation itself does not contribute a signature to the overload set.

Comment: The function can return an array. It depends on the asObject property.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Comment: But why it's not recognize the default value?   function get(options: Options = {asObject: false, other: () => {}}): any[] | MyMap<any> {
}

Comment: This still infered as MyMap

Comment: Because the implementation signature of an overload does not contribute to the overload set.

Comment: I'm not sure that I get it. Can you add the solution to the answer, please? Marking it as the answer.

Comment: So how can I support default a parameter?

Comment: You can have default parameters, just as you do now, but they won't influence the type of the function because defaults can only appear in a functions implementation.

Comment: Now, if I didn't pass anything, the type is MyMap<any>. It should be any[]

Comment: See updated answer. Note that overload ordering is significant when parameter types are compatible