# Typescript function overloading with object - Implementation signatures of overloads are not externally visible

Tags: typescript, object, generics, overloading, signature

### Problem

How can I expose an overloading implementation signature correctly?

### Example

Building off of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309376/typescript-function-overloading-with-object):

```js
interface MyMap<T> {
  [id: string]: T;
}

type Options = {
  asObject?: boolean,
  other?: Function
  testing?: number
};


function get(options: { asObject: true, other?: Function, testing?:number }): MyMap<any>;
function get(options: { asObject?: false,  other?: Function, testing?:number }): number[];
function get(): any[];
function get(options: Options = { asObject: false }): any[] | MyMap<any> {
    if (options?.asObject) return {} as MyMap<any>;

    return [];
}
```

How can I wrap this function but retain the possible return types depending on the options argument?

For example:

```js
function wrapFunction(arg1 arg2, options) { 
   // do something with arg1 and arg2

   return get(options) 
}
```

Depending on the value set for options in the wrapFunction method, the return type would be based on the return type of get with that same value.

ie:

```js
const g = wrapFunction(1,2, {asObject: true}) 

// Should return the same thing as get({asObject:true})
```

### Attempted Solutions

I could simply rewrite a new signature for the wrapFunction, but this would be quite verbose, especially if I have many types of wrapFunctions that follow the same pattern of having a nested `get` call.

One [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65910266/typescript-function-overloading-with-object-implementation-signatures-of-overl?noredirect=1#comment116603535_65910266) was to type cast the wrapFunction as `typeof get` but this removes the ability to modify the parameters list of wrapFunction.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598280/is-it-possible-to-wrap-a-function-and-retain-its-types/54946767#54946767) might be related.

### Related Links

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=32&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE9VwA4B4AqAfMgN4BQyyA2sACYBcyAzmFKAOYC6j+A3GQF8yZMOmwoA8tjDAA9iCbIAvKQrI4TCQCMAVhARgA-Iy2zZAGwhwQAGjWywAC2jHkAMQCuIA3JBrILByuIB4AtlrQgvzCMF4+8sjsEGAAFLLSvkyMJOqauvpgjKweEDbIDs5Qrp7eMvJlATIg7MYh4dDIAgCUjBhYeNbohPyxtb6JyWkZ8lmkudp6Bq7w5kyllBUujDXxtsiNQfRtEVCdPcjH0FScI3F1IBOp54PXt2MJSanp97NSP8pzDQLAqMFZrM6MF6cZAAHzQmBwuEGxHIlEowBgyCmP0MADogfkDF1kFBkh4oA8SAJcvD+kiQENomiSWSKdQboIYndxuxsZliTlSWByQ9PnyZsShGQEDMwMgtADeTkCYtCvsoCUzmQgA)

Comment: It looks like your playground link is broken. But I don't understand what you mean by 'externally' calling the code? You mean how do you export the function correctly?

Comment: @Aron Fixed! See how Im calling the get function from within another function? I wasn't sure of the best way to describe that besides, calling the signatures externally

Comment: Just expose overload with same signature as implementation https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE9VwA4B4AqAfMgN4BQyyA2sACYBcyAzmFKAOYC6j+A3GQF8yZMOmwoA8tjDAA9iCbIAvKQrI4TCQCMAVhARgA-Iy2zZAGwhwQAGjWywAC2jHkAMQCuIA3JBrILByuIB4AtlrQgvzCMF4+8sjsEGAAFLLSvkyMJOqauvpgjKweKAIAlIwYWHjW6IT8sd4yCUmp6c0Krjka2noGjPDmTKUV6iDoVJwNcR2JyWkZ8kyuUh1Mo7WTyAA+aJg4uLX1MTO+c22LnYyrmRvjW7tVB0eqlMAwyAtrhgB0PfkGMrIKDJDxQECkAS5PbVQ7jY5qEFgMEQyb8IRkRrxCHsL6ZFaXdakYGg8HnPFLIEYhBLMDILTKRIpbp5PqFZDFEZkIA

Comment: @AlekseyL. doing that removes the type specificity. For example, the type of b here:

`const b = g({ asObject: true })` is going to be `any[] | MyMap<any>`, not just the  `MyMap<any>` from the first signature.

Comment: It doesn't remove anything, it behaves this way because `g` has following signature: `function g(options?: Options) ...`  where `options?: Options` makes it resolve to the third overload

Comment: Oh I understand, i reworded my question in the post! See if that makes more sense @AlekseyL.

Comment: You could reuse type of original function. Not sure if that helps: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE9VwA4B4AqAfMgN4BQyyA2sACYBcyAzmFKAOYC6j+A3GQF8yZMOmwoA8tjDAA9iCbIAvKQrI4TCQCMAVhARgA-Iy2zZAGwhwQAGjWywAC2jHkAMQCuIA3JBrILByuIB4AtlrQgvzCMF4+8sjsEGAAFLLSvkyMJOqauvpgjKweKAIAlIwYWHjW6IT8sd4yCUmp6c0Krjka2noGjPDmTKUV6iDoVJwNcR2JyWkZ8kyuUh1Mo7WTyAA+aJg4uLX1ZI3xIHNti52Mq5kb41u7VQdHqpTAMMgLa4YAdD35AxlZBQZIeKDnEgCXJ7aqHcbHNSgsDg86TfhCMgIJZgRLKL7fTI3K7rZTEVqEpZlYEaZCicSyT6taLYhS42QAN2g5lkcFoAEZ8ewUt08n1CnSoCVkOVkAB6OWwl4IrE45Cc7m82gAJiFItyvQKAzgQxG8sVm04ZCAA

Comment: Definitely closer to what I'm looking for! Though that sort of technique would break if the parent function arguments were altered in anyway no? (Ill update the question with an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

To fix this problem I made use of conditional types. For example:

```js
// This is the switch interface
interface Switch<T> {
  on: T
}

// This is the conditional type.
type ExtendReturn<E extends boolean, R extends string | number > = E extends true
  ? Array<R>
  : number;

/*
First solution, using the conditional type and type inference. This requires a
nested structure and returns a curry-like function. The inner function separates out all the generics that should be inferred, and the outer function contains the generic that should be set explicitly 
*/
function test3<R extends string | number = string>() { 
  return function inner<E extends boolean>(options: Switch<E>): ExtendReturn<E, R> {
    const r = options.on ? 's' : 4

    return r as ExtendReturn<E, R>
  }
}

// Notice the extra (), but each of the types are inferred correctly
const a = test3<number>()({ on: true })


/*
Second Solution, using a combination of overload methods, and the conditional
type. This is a bit more verbose, but removes the requirement of the currying
structure, keeping a cleaner API.
*/
function test4<R extends string | number = string>(options?: Switch<false>): ExtendReturn<false, R>;
function test4<R extends string | number = string>(options: Switch<true>): ExtendReturn<true, R>;
function test4<E extends boolean, R extends string | number = string>(options?: Switch<E>): ExtendReturn<E, R> {
  const r = options?.on ? 's' : 4

  return r as ExtendReturn<E, R>
}

// Notice the simpler API
const m = test4<string>({ on: true })
```

The full comparison can be seen [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=12&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHdhgQCwDwAqAfMgN4BQyyA9iAFzIHkC+55YAngA4oCiAHpBAATAEoQwAVyghCyCIIgiAzsgBG1agBsIcECQC8jeYpXIwUSRErIA-MmUXQAcxsMQkgLZroAbjbkMJIgCGDAtOYQjnIKQsKqGtq6+gAU1FxhtMoMGFi4hEQAlAwCceJSMgVkNghZYMhQyEbpmSDKAHQR9gDkyt3IDAAsbFRQEtIgDchwqqVKYuOVxCxsnDzIcyLlEwBMeLwmcQmaOnoANMiih-OqjlAuyAA+yB7e0MiGG9dmFlY29gBBKBQOAcPCiIhuF5eHxQfyBYKhcKTSCOPYHWI3dQnZIXK6Ysx3B7PV6wpoOJwgZxENIZZHZNCYbD4XhFEqmBYVEDovEkChUWpteqNZp0rKdSY9PoDZDDGxjLlTGYbDnbGQ8y6Q1jsKJgPa-CAXUnQGmkGj0cyWFDMQpsAD0duQAAloChgKpaChlNpJK0ESFWpFHABmcHfeIU+5Up7Qt4iyMuGmFMjIeWLSZBAPI5CgEDQfbh45JPQ0lr0nJM-Ks4oqsrpjUQ6pUAV1Kai1odLrIXr9IYjZsKiZK2aq+v7Xk2VjawWOabk1FgUPGqBJlJm2gMA3IG32x2oH2Bnb+pERBeDMMEiNE6MkmHvIzX6m0ju2Ct5fDwLTKCBs2vzNXcngn7fry-iZieKK6ue+IcrclLODGy7ko+pZim0b7MngBq-psnK7FhVqgcegZngWl5FqcIB4oWCY3rGZIPvBqEvhhVY4aOXINnyNStvGZZZLYEp2N20p9mmiqNMquEAVxKxsDO9SePOUF4Cha7mpuVrboUQA)

### Thoughts

These are workarounds for this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), but sufficiently solve the problem. For complex scenarios, or perhaps a hidden API, using the currying method looks cleaner, avoiding the need for many overload methods. Similarly, more basic scenarios or public API's lend themselves to the second solution.