# Typescript, overloading a function with object argument

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an argument object and returns an object. The returned object will contain a "bar" key depending if the "includeBar" key is provided as an option. I tried the following overload

```js
interface Options {
    includeBar: boolean
}

interface Return {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

function someFunc(opt: Options & { includeBar: true }): Return;
function someFunc(opt: Options & { includeBar: false }): Omit<Return, "bar">;
function someFunc(opt: any): any {
    // ...
}

const { bar: bar1 } = someFunc({ includeBar: true }); // OK bar1 exists
const { bar: bar2 } = someFunc({ includeBar: false }); // OK bar2 does not exists
```

It works fine until I pass a declared object to myFunc:

```js
const options: Options = {
    includeBar: true
}

const { bar } = someFunc(options); // TS Error Types of property 'includeBar' are incompatible. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.
```

Here is a sample [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQHkAOEQHswDOqA3sKuauEgDYCuAJlAEIIwBcqARrrtVAmGABfYKEixEKVACUoEWjDAkyFODw4EIMcAHMA3CvKdWGrboMjgcWmCQ58qArgC2UAGI2kAClzYOWe0JUADISSls6RhZ2VC1aNCEASg5ZeUUDa1tAxxd3Tx8-DGw8INDicJoGZhNURGoCBOSMZxAIAB5UhTAAGlQAImMYPoA%20DM9sp1cPWwKIDgEATybF5QpUAHp11AA6XeFRJHxNMMGOQYBGVCFUAF4cqfzyqkjqmLjGvQ2t9ABpLlZLlAAB4gTQEYCHQgQE41QYAJiut3ueRmTwiVWiHDqDSuiU%20mwwf3hqHouCgRDAuGhwNBEHBEKO0N8gQI-mKRyRpDWzwxNXe%20wZUJhMERd0mKO8zJKBDxX1QABUAMqoACiMBguBgom1QA)

I saw [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309376/typescript-function-overloading-with-object) but the answer has the same problem once the function is given a declared object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the following changes to your declaration of options...

```
const options = {
    includeBar: true
} as const;
```

Then Typescript can tell that

1. options has a narrower type than Options
2. options won't have had its
   values changed at runtime since declaration.

Comment: I would never had thought about that thanks, though it's limitating: say that my options object comes from a wrapping function: function wrappingFunc(options: Options) { return myFunc(options) }. I can't use the const syntax here.

Comment: I sketched out an improved function signature for your overloads which allows the narrower type to be preserved through the call stack which you can [see here](https://tsplay.dev/WoqZ9N). However, I didn't share that originally as it was a different problem.

Comment: Indeed it is but thanks for sharing anyway